# php pass parameter issue

Tags: php, parameters, hyperlink, echo

This my code:

```
<?php
$lijstDoelmannen = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Speler WHERE positie = 'Doelman' ORDER BY familienaam, voornaam");
$teller = 1;
while($rij = mysql_fetch_array($lijstDoelmannen))
{
    if($teller < 5){
        echo "<td><a href='spelerDetail.php?spelerId='" . $rij['id'] . "><img src='images/spelers/unknown.png' alt='' width='50' />
            <br /><br />" . $rij["id"] . " " . $rij['familienaam'] . " " . $rij['voornaam'] . "</a></td>";
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is that in the hyperlink the parameter spelerId = spaces (not filled in). If I echo `$rij["id"]`, it gives me the right value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `'` in the wrong spot in your `href`.

```
"...<a href='spelerDetail.php?spelerId='" . $rij['id'] . ">..."
```

This should be:

```
"...<a href='spelerDetail.php?spelerId=" . $rij['id'] . "'>..."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='spelerDetail.php?spelerId='" . $rij['id'] . ">
```

You need to move the apostrophe:

```
<a href='spelerDetail.php?spelerId=" . $rij['id'] . "'>
```

It's currently ending the link, before the variable is added.

Comment: @Rocket - sorry, I'm clearly having a senior moment. I can't for the life of me see what's wrong with those quotes.

Comment: ... but it's not been changed. I'm terribly confused!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
echo "<td><a href='spelerDetail.php?spelerId={$rij['id']}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($rij = mysql_fetch_array($lijstDoelmannen))
{
if($teller < 5){
    echo "<td><a href='spelerDetail.php?spelerId='" . $rij['id'] . "><img src='images/spelers/unknown.png' alt='' width='50' />
        <br /><br />" . $rij["id"] . " " . $rij['familienaam'] . " " . $rij['voornaam'] . "</a></td>";
}
}
?>
```

I prefer writing the above code this way to avid these types of issues:

```
while($rij = mysql_fetch_array($lijstDoelmannen)){
if($teller < 5){ ?>
    <td><a href="spelerDetail.php?spelerId=<?php echo $rij['id'] ?>">
    <img src="images/spelers/unknown.png" alt="" width="50" />
    <br /><br /><?php echo $rij['id'] . " " . $rij['familienaam'] . " " . $rij['voornaam'] ?></a></td>
<?php }} ?>
```